# Hide element on scroll and make it visible again at top of screen

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide a span with the class 'menu-text' on scroll and make it reappear when at the top of the screen.

I have tried the following but none of them seem to work:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("mousewheel", function() {
    if($(document).scrollTop() < 50){
        $('.menu-text').css("display","block");
    } else {
        $('.menu-text').css("display","none");
    }; 
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50) {
      $(".menu-text").addClass("hidden");
    } else {
       $(".menu-text").removeClass("hidden");
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("mousewheel", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50) {
      $(".menu-text").hide();
    } else {
       $(".menu-text").show();
    }
  });
});
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

This is the HTML for the element:

```
<button id="open-button" class="hamburger menu-button hamburger--spin" type="button">
  <span class="menu-text">MENU</span>
  <span class="hamburger-box">
<span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
</span>

</button>
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you included the relevant html and use the `<>` snippet editor

Comment: In your second code block check what does the line $(this).scrollTop() return. The if condition seems to always fail that's why your logic is not executing.

Comment: Any of those should work. If they aren't then you have an issue somewhere else in your page, possibly in the HTML or CSS. We need a complete snippet showing the behaviour in order to help you debug this problem

Comment: I have added some HTML including the element I am trying to hide

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki how do I do this?

Comment: Use console.log($(this).scrollTop()); to check what is the scroll position. And if you want to execute the if condition block before any scroll then you need to write the show hide logic directly in the .ready function.

Answer (score 0):

I Edited Your Code you can achieve your task by using this code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
  width:800px;
  height:1500px;
}
</style>
<button id="open-button" class="hamburger menu-button hamburger--spin" type="button" style="position:fixed;">
  <span class="menu-text">MENU</span>
  <span class="hamburger-box">
<span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
</span>
</button>
<script>
$(function() {
  $(document).on("mousewheel", function() {
     if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50) {
        $('.menu-text').css("display","block");
    } else {
       $('.menu-text').css("display","none");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```